# editButtonItem set but no minus buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My edit button is placed in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

It shows up correctly on the nav bar, and tapping this button indeed change it to Done. However, no minus buttons show up in my table rows. Swiping a row, then tap Delete works, though.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** Here's how I'm doing:

```
- (void)loadView {
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

self.view = tableView;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** My observation is that the edit and minus buttons display fine if my tableview is created in IB (RootViewController). The other two (or three) tableview are created by the aforemention code, so that might be the problem. Guess I'd have to dive in to isEditing, editing and whatnot.

Comment: What are you overloading?  Is it just a plain ol' UITableViewController?  Are your UITableViewCells doing anything strange (subclassed or otherwise)?  Are you doing anything funny in the view controller when returning the editable type of a row?

Comment: Yeah, it's just plain ol' UITableViewController. I'd clarify my post by adding some code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Silly me. I forgot to change UIViewController (the class my view controller inherits from) to UITableViewController. Now, it works.

Without doing this, I would need to enable row editing manually like:

```
// in loadView
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(turnOnEditing)];

- (void)turnOnEditing {
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(turnOffEditing)];
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)turnOffEditing {
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(turnOnEditing)];
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 39):

If you don't subclass UITableViewController, there is a way to do it. Just implement setEditing:animated: in your UIViewController subclass as follows:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing: editing animated: animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

*Note: replace "self.tableView" if needed...*

Also add the "edit" buttonto the toolbar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

And that's all!

Comment: You, (sir or madam), are a genius.

Answer (score 2):

To show and to activate the minus button at the left corner of each of the tableviewcell, do the following:

Add the following code to your viewdidload method:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

//The above line is to show the "EDIT" and "DONE" button on the top right corner of your navigation bar.

And also add the following method to your .m file to show and animate the MINUS sign on the tableview cells.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing == YES) {

    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

     } else {

    [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:animated];

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do:

```
self.tableView = tableView;
```

in your `loadView` method.  That's the property that `UITableViewController` manipulates, and it gets set automatically if you're loading the view from a NIB.  Since you're creating the view programatically, you need to set it explicitly.

Comment: There's no need to do this. The most important thing to remember is to change the parent class from UIViewController to UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. According to the docs for UITableViewController, it reads: UITableViewController implements the superclass method setEditing:animated: so that if a user taps an Edit|Done button in the navigation bar, the controller toggles the edit mode of the table.

See the last bullet point in the [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doc.